# How can I control Arc Lighter circuit with esp8266 d1 mini

Tags: arduino, mosfet

Here's an arc lighter that turns on when pressing down on the top left button. My question is, what is the easiest way to control the (on/off) of this lighter using only the esp8266 d1 mini.

[image: Arc lighter circuit]

Comment: how does the top left button interact with the circuit when it is pressed?

Comment: I think you mean when the button is released on the enclosed setup transformer.  I suggest a high voltage NPN >100V which is transformed to >2kV/mm